# How to prevent Power Menu Options at lockscreen activity?

Tags: java, android

I am having an idea to prevent showing up Power OFF options at lockscreen when power button is pressed for short period of time! By this to prevent unauthorized power off and to save the phone from thieves! I did little research on this..but I cant find the right answer, whether we can do it or we cant as its related to OS framework? 
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will have to recompile the Android OS with a few code changes.**

> - Lockscreen -> Power Off
> - Power Off -> Hold

**This is buried deep in the codebase, good luck.**

> At least 250GB of free disk space to check out the code and an extra 150 GB to build it. If you conduct multiple builds, you need additional space. linux os is required to build this, if you use a virtual machine you will be required to have 16 GB of RAM/swap.

***Links:***

- [Android OS Source](https://source.android.com/)
- [Android OS Develop](https://source.android.com/setup/develop)
- [StackOverflow related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54260/what-is-an-alternate-way-to-switch-off-mobile-without-use-of-power-button)

Comment: I want to create an app to prevent power off the device...or to prevent the shutdown sequence! So this can be possible or not?

Comment: since you want to "block" the power feature, you'll need to do low level system code changes..

Comment: why cant we distract users by diverting them to another activity or opening another instance, while they press power button

Comment: you cannot re-assign the "hold" press, but the  single press would work fine.

Comment: wrte a custome homescreen activity

Comment: even i do the custom homescreen activity....but still hold action will work...and the device will pop power menu options...I dont want to pop that options by any means!

Comment: to stop that menu, you will have to edit the OS/Firmware code.

Comment: then flash the built rom onto the phone.

Comment: Okay! Got it! Thank you! Is there any other way to prevent power off device from lockscreen?